# Django REST framework: Getting 403 when trying to test create a new post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to create a test for creating a new post, but I'm getting Error 403. I've read the questions on this topic, but either they were not about testing or the solution they provided did not work (I'll provide info about what I've tried so far).

Here is my code:

urls.py:

```
app_name = "blog_api"


urlpatterns = [
    path("<str:pk>/", PostDetail.as_view(), name="detail_create"),
    path("", PostList.as_view(), name="list_create"),
]
```

and my permissions.py:

```
class PostUserWritePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "Editing posts is restricted to the admin and author of the post only."

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return request.user.is_superuser or request.user == obj.author
```

And here is my views.py:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Post.post_objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [PostUserWritePermission]
    queryset = Post.post_objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

And finally, my tests.py:

```
class PostTests(APITestCase):
    def test_view_posts(self):
        url = reverse("blog_api:list_create")
        response = self.client.get(url, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_create_post(self):
        self.test_category = Category.objects.create(name="test category")
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="test_user",
            password="test_password",
        )
        data = {
            "title": "new",
            "author": 1,
            "excerpt": "new",
            "content": "new",
            "slug": "new",
        }
        url = reverse("blog_api:list_create")
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format="json")

        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

So, when I test using `py manage.py test` command, the first test is ok, but the second one returns `error 403`, and when I tried to see the response message using `print(response.data)` this is what's printed:

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Authentication credentials were not provided.', code='not_authenticated')}
```

I should also mention that I have this setting in my `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly",
    ],
}
```

I did some searching about this, [this one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156274/django-testing-client-post-request-getting-403-error) was a bit similar to my problem, but I create my user using `create_user` method, thus his solution is irrelevant to my question.
What am I missing here?

WHAT I"VE TRIED:

I tried to comment out the permision class `PostUserWritePermission` in the `PostDetail` view, but got the same error nonetheless.

Also I tried to solve this by adding `TokenAuthentication` to my settings, but this didn't work neither.

Comment: You're creating the user, but not logging in. Try logging in the user first: `self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')`

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans After adding this, first I got the error `{'author': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "1" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}` which was a bit odd, so I used `"author": User.objects.first().id` and it worked. Thank you for the first answer, but got any idea about the second one?

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans I printed `User.objects.first().id` and it was 2 :/ Why is that? I'm creating this user in the alias database so there should not be any user beforhand.